# Partial application and sortBy

Tags: haskell, partial-application

I'm learning Haskell and I've been experimenting with partial application.
I tried to pertially apply sortBy. I don't undestand the type of the resulting function.
And how should it be done properly?

```
let mf = sortBy compare
:t mf
mf :: [()] -> [()]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the monomorphism restriction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496864/what-is-the-monomorphism-restriction)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of the dreaded [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) and ghci's defaulting behaviour. This should solve it:

```
λ> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
λ> import Data.List (sortBy)
λ> let mf = sortBy compare
λ> :t mf
mf :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

The short story being because of monomorphic restriction, the compiler will try to reduce your function definition to a single type (in your case `[()] -> [()]`). But without the restriction, you get a polymorphic type (`Ord a => [a] -> [a]`) as constrained by the typeclass.

Comment: Or `let mf x = sortBy compare x` if you don't want to use `NoMonomorphismRestriction`

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing an artifact the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.5.5).

```
Prelude Data.List> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction 
Prelude Data.List> let mf = sortBy compare
Prelude Data.List> :t mf
mf :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```